# drop NaN, None datatypes while converting dataframe to list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["str",None,"aad","asd"],[None,"ddd",None,pd.NaT],["xyz",None,"abc",None],["btc","trz","abd",pd.NaT]],columns=list('ABCD'))
```

I want to have a list with only string values in it.

Example:

```
[['str', 'aad', 'asd'],['ddd'], ['xyz','abc'], ['btc', 'trz', 'abd']]
```

I tried

```
df.values.tolist()
```

but I got complete list with None, NaT and NaN values.

is there any way to just keep string values and drop other datatypes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If want remove `NaN`, `None` and `NaT` use [`notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.notna.html) use list comprehension with another one nested with filtarion:

```
a = [[y for y in x if pd.notna(y)] for x in df.values.tolist()]
print (a)
[['str', 'aad', 'asd'], ['ddd'], ['xyz', 'abc'], ['btc', 'trz', 'abd']]
```

Or if want filter only strings use `isinstance` for condition:

```
a = [[y for y in x if isinstance(y, str)] for x in df.values.tolist()]
```

Comment: Worked like charm. If you have moment can you please explain in brief?

Comment: @aminsama - Sure, I try add some explanation, not sure it it is enough

Answer (score 1):

```
I hope this gives you implicit understanding about what @jezrael explains

whole_list=[]
for row in df.values.tolist():
    partial_list=[]
    for column in row:
        if pd.notna(column):
            partial_list.append(column)
    whole_list.append(partial_list)
whole_list
```

Comment: really appreciate effort to explain it.

Comment: Thank you.  I am glad that you understood

Answer (score -2):

you can easily drop them with a method which pandas provided name `dropna()` so you can use it both for index or column you can use it like ..

```
DataFrame.dropna(self, axis=0, how='any', thresh=None, subset=None, inplace=False)
```

in your case df.dropna() if you wanna drop from your column you are gonna pass axis=1 nor as default it is zero. 
also you can use the documentation for more details
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html

this will drop the whole row or columns , you can also use some functions to check it , you can use `notnull()` or `fillna()` for having that.
i hope it helps

Comment: No, it remove all rows with at least one missing value.

Comment: OP need removed missing values per lists, not per rows. Do you test it with sample data?